# javascript innerhtml show value only for a short time

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

following function should write a value on my html page:

```
function f(){
var aa;
aa = document.getElementById("a");
document.getElementById('resultarea').innerHTML += aa;
}
```

It works, but the value appears only for a few milliseconds. Then the value is gone.
What is the problem? Why do my page a reset?

html code:

```
   <div>
  <form>
     <label for="a">a:</label>
     <input type="number" name="a" id="a" />
     <button onclick="f()">Calculate</button>

  </form>
</div>
<div id="resultarea"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The default action for a button in a `form` is to submit the form (which triggers a POST request, essentially reloading the page in this case).

You need to add `type="button"` to the button to prevent this behavior, or `.preventDefault()` on the event.

```js
function f() {
  var aa;
  aa = document.getElementById("a");
  document.getElementById('resultarea').innerHTML += aa.value;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <label for="a">a:</label>
    <input type="number" name="a" id="a" />
    <button onclick="f()" type="button">Calculate</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="resultarea"></div>
```

Comment: that was it - many thanks! I searched hours and doesn't found it...

Comment: @Hias Most of this is documented in the MDN guide: [Sending form data](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) and [Client-side form validation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation). Also, Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.